# Do I have duplicate packages?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, java, duplicate

I get the following error after running `sudo apt-get update` (Linux Mint 12):

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg/ debs/all i386 Packages
   (/var/lib/apt/lists/www.duinsoft.nl_pkg_dists_debs_all_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

[FSlint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint) doesn't find duplicates in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. I found these files by browsing `/var/lib/apt/lists`:

`www.duinsoft.nl_pkg_dists_debs_all_binary-i386_Packages`, Size: 3.3 kB
`www.duinsoft.nl_pkg_dists_debs_release`, Size: 2.9 kB
`www.duinsoft.nl_pkg_dists_debs_release.gpg`, Size: 490 Bytes.

This is somehow connected to a Java installation. Would deleting any of these files help fixing the error?

Comment: it says `You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems` but `apt-get update` does not fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have duplicate packages.

As it says you have a duplicate entry in your `sources.list` (located in `/etc/apt`). How you fix this can depend on the package manager(s) you use. If you want to go straight to the `sources.list`, open a Terminal and type the following command.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Look for the duplicate. You can disable entries by putting a `#` at the beginning of the line or by removing duplicate lines.

http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs/all

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the duplicated lines.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `/etc/apt/sources.list` AND `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` - the later being used by e.g. automated added PPAs.